# Line feed in BizTalk 2016 xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am converting some BizTalk maps/xslt from 2010 to 2016 and run into problem with line feeds. I want a LF in the result (not CRLF) but when I test the map in Visual Studio I end up with CRLF in the result. The same happens if I run it in Biztalk.

I have tried to insert the LF with `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` and in C# code `"\n"` but both results in CRLF in the output.

I find some general documentation about XmlWriterSettings [XmlWriterSettings.NewLineHandling Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling(v=vs.110).aspx) but is it possible to change the setting to "Entitize" in a BizTalk map somewhere?

Comment: Since xml doesn't require whitespaces remove all white spaces using XmlWriteSettings then you shouldn't have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but make sure to use passthrough pipeline during runtime.